# Error To show Data Parsed Json In Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dio

I Have One Http Post Method Like This :

```
class ApiClientController extends GetxController {
Future<GetSideMenuInfoError?> GetInfoAfterLogin() async {
    String? value = await storage.read(key: 'skey');
    try {
      final response = await dio.post(
        Constant.baseUrl,
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            "omax-apikey": "apikey",
          },
        ),
        data: {
          "function": "portal_get_information",
          "params": {
          "portal_version": "1.0.0",
          "portal_os": "linux",
          "portal_os_version": "10",
          "portal_browser": "chrome",
          "portal_guid": "fd298776-6014-11ed-adbc-5256454165"
          }
        },
      );
       
     //print(response.data.toString());   
     
      GetSideMenuInfoError? responseBody = getSideMenuInfoErrorFromJson(response.data.toString());      
      return responseBody;

    } on DioError catch (e) {
      //return ;
      print(e);
      
    }
      return null;

    //IMPLEMENT USER LOGIN
  }

 }
```

And The Result Post Method My Json :

```
{
    "result": 55456465,
    "data": {
        "reason": "session expired or not valid",
        "uuid": "01dfca14-625559-11ed-aafa-0056546546"
    }
}
```

Used This https://app.quicktype.io/ for Parsed Json To dart File Result Like This:

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

GetSideMenuInfoError? getSideMenuInfoErrorFromJson(String str) => GetSideMenuInfoError?.fromJson(json.decode(str));


class GetSideMenuInfoError {
    GetSideMenuInfoError({
        @required this.result,
        @required this.data,
    });

    final int? result;
    final Data? data;

    factory GetSideMenuInfoError.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetSideMenuInfoError(
        result: json["result"],
        data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
    );

   
}

class Data {
    Data({
        @required this.reason,
        @required this.uuid,
    });

    final String? reason;
    final String? uuid;

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        reason: json["reason"],
        uuid: json["uuid"],
    );

}
```

And My Question Is : How Can I Show value in Dart File Like reason or uuid In Other Class ?
My Way like This in Other Class And Not Worked:
In The Build Widget :

```
 final apiClientController = Get.find<ApiClientController>();
  apiClientController.GetInfoAfterLogin();
 GetSideMenuInfoError? getSideMenuInfoError;
 title: getSideMenuInfoError != null ? 
 Text(getSideMenuInfoError.result.toString()):Text('',),
```

Thank You For Helping Me...

Comment: Did you save your data in any state management?

Comment: you can save your data in local storage or create singleton class and use that class to access your data in all your project.

Comment: My Main Class Method Like This: class ApiClientController extends GetxController {} use getx..and before instance GetSideMenuInfoError put ApiClientController to My class,but not see Anything in Text Widget and Say Text null

Comment: can you include ApiClientController too?

Comment: of course update my post and added just 3 line first my api controller just 1 line:class ApiClientController extends GetxController { my method} and before use them just add 2 line like this:  final apiClientController = Get.find<ApiClientController>();
  apiClientController.GetInfoAfterLogin(); in other class with get.put hold my apiClasses instance

Comment: when print the response body see my json in console but not correctly parsed and show in Text Widget or Other Widget